# Android third party jar- deal with naming

Tags: android, jar

I have a problem, I am developing right now library project that is using some third party libs, and I would like to somehow rename that libs to use the convention MYLIBRARY_GSON.jar or something like that, how would I accomplish such task? I have been looking and looking and found fatJar however I dont think thats the one I need. Oh and I am using gradle building system.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how would I accomplish such task?

Rename the JAR using a file explorer in your development operating system. Or, use the appropriate command-line operation (e.g., **`mv`** in Linux).

Bear in mind that the JAR file name only exists on your development machine, plus perhaps on any other machines to which you distribute your library project. The name of a JAR file has no runtime impact and is not included in the APK of an app.

Comment: Then when I am using lets say gson 4.2 in my library project and then include it inside other project I may use the same gson 4.2 library without any problems? Thats what bothers me

Comment: @user3274539: That has nothing to do with the JAR's file name. It has everything to do with the classes inside the JAR. If you are using Gradle, your library project should not have Gson in it anyway -- it should be a dependency, pulled from Maven Central. Then, if the app using your library *also* references Gson as a dependency, you won't have two copies of Gson to begin with.